# What do draft and swine mean?

Tags: british-english, slang, understanding

the passage's from Frankenstein play. it's a part of the opening song. What do draft and swine mean?
Come gather ye
feast on our Empire's riches

New heaven on Earth
shall to all ages rise

Those ravenous dogs
singing sweet hallelujah

The angels will feed on the draft and the swine.

Comment: Could you provide more context, e.g. a complete verse of the song? Without this, I'd guess 'draft' = 'draft beer' and 'swine' = 'porc'.

Comment: Draft animals are those that pull loads or carry them: horses, oxen, buffalo, donkeys, etc. Swine are pigs. All of these animals can be eaten.

Comment: @Glorfindel I add it!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Can you explain more about the sentence?

Comment: The angels will eat the cattle and pigs. That's it.

Comment: @user103409 - who wrote this play? When? Where?

Comment: @Michael Harvey It is an adaptation from 2011 by Danny Boyle.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Note that it would be spelled _draught_ in British English. I've never heard of draught animals being called just 'draught', but I can't think of any other meaning either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing anything else about the context, I agree that Michael Harvey's comment is most probable:

> Draft animals are those that pull loads or carry them: horses, oxen, buffalo, donkeys, etc. Swine are pigs. All of these animals can be eaten.

This is in opposition to Glorfindel's comment:

> I'd guess 'draft' = 'draft beer' and 'swine' = 'porc' [sic].

Note: "porc" should be spelled "pork", in case you are new to English.

There are a couple reasons why *draft* most likely refers to *draft animals* here:

- One does not *feed on* beer. Beer is a liquid, and liquids cannot be eaten.
- The addition of *swine* in a way completes *the draft* because both (presumably) refer to animals, but pigs do not generally pull or carry loads and are for that reason not considered draft animals. It seems like the intention was to make sure that swine and other non-draft animals are not perceived to be excluded from the terrible fate that awaits horses, oxen, etc.

Also, *pork* can be synonymous with *swine* or refer more specifically to pig meat. I suppose either interpretation is acceptable here, as *pork* signifies the edible parts of swine.

Hope this helps!